# Best way to create report and template in ReportServer Community

Tags: jasper-reports, reportserver

Currently in my work I started using [ReportServer](https://bitnami.com/stack/reportserver), I researched and apparently the way to create reports here is through other tools like JaspeReport, is this so?
I also have the need to generate a template (or background) that will change in this report, how is this done? Should I do it in JasperReport or ReportServer can do it?

Comment: Why don't you simply use iReport or Jasper Report ? 
If the goal is the same then why not, I've never used ReportServer from what I've understood you need Jasper Report to make reports with ReportServer, so why make things complicated ? unless you're obliged to

Comment: I'm obligated :c, I dont know other solutions, but ReportServer allows to create dashboards, schedule the sending of reports and take snapshots in some definite time

Comment: You don't even use Jaspersoft Studio ? It's doing the exact same thing, creating dashboards and it has Jasper Report integrated. I can't help you exactly with your problem since I've never used ReportServer but I know the solution surely exists in Jasper Report.
I've checked ReportServer, there's literally an entire user guide and installation manual etc : https://reportserver.net/en/documentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JasperStudio by tibco is typically used to create a Jasper report. ReportServer is a BI server with which you can use different report formats (Jasper, Birt, Crystal) together in one server. At https://reportserver.net/en/documentation/ you will find a comprehensive documentation and at https://forum.reportserver.net/ a user forum for ReportServer questions.